# Error on time series based data that bins are monotomically increasing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pd.cut but getting error that bins must increase monotomically. But i do not mention bins in the code.

Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from google.colab import files
f= files.upload()
df=pd.read_excel(r'symbol1_second.xlsx',index_col='date',parse_dates=True)
df.head()
states=3
def get_edges(df, states):
  edges = {}
  series = df.columns
  for s in series:
    std = df[s].std()
    edges[s] = [std*(-states/2+x) for x in range(states+1)][1:-1]
    edges[s].append(df[s].max())
    edges[s].insert(0,df[s].min())
  return edges
edges = get_edges(df, states) 
g = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in edges.items():
  g[key] = pd.cut(df[key],value,labels=False, include_lowest=True)
```

Below is the error showing in the code

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-435fbb9cd8dc> in <module>()
     20 g = pd.DataFrame()
     21 for key, value in edges.items():
---> 22   g[key] = pd.cut(df[key],value,labels=False, include_lowest=True)
     23   tm.assert_numpy_array_equal(g[key].codes,
     24                                 np.array([0, 0, 1], dtype="int8"))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    253         # GH 26045: cast to float64 to avoid an overflow
    254         if (np.diff(bins.astype("float64")) < 0).any():
--> 255             raise ValueError("bins must increase monotonically.")
    256 
    257     fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(

ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.
```

Comment: Your 'values' variable is being taken as bins.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug in pandas [pd.cut](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26045).
Try updating your working environment to pandas version 0.25.0 and check it out.

Comment: Then the problem should be with your data. Can you share the head of your input dataframe?

Comment: bidcash bidfut
date  
2020-05-04 09:15:01 18200 18210
2020-05-04 09:15:02 18130 18150
2020-05-04 09:15:03 18085 18065
2020-05-04 09:15:04 18105 18105
2020-05-04 09:15:05 18100 18155

Comment: Mainly with date there are two markets date which are more or less random.